# How to get geom_smooth() ignore my colour grouping

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to make a plot with fitted lines for two levels of my factor(grouped by color). I used shapes to group another variant but when I try to fit smoother, I end up with 4 lines while I only need one two lines in total (1 per color)

Here is the data and code I use:

```
data <- structure(list(K = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("2s", "4s"), class = "factor"), 
    q = c(0.12, 0.11, 0.1, 0.09, 0.08, 0.07, 0.06, 0.05, 0.04, 
    0.03, 0.02, 0.01, 0.12, 0.11, 0.1, 0.09, 0.08, 0.07, 0.06, 
    0.05, 0.04, 0.03, 0.02, 0.01, 0.12, 0.11, 0.1, 0.09, 0.08, 
    0.07, 0.06, 0.05, 0.04, 0.03, 0.02, 0.01, 0.12, 0.11, 0.1, 
    0.09, 0.08, 0.07, 0.06, 0.05, 0.04, 0.03, 0.02, 0.01), rarity = c(0.907, 
    0.9206, 0.9359, 0.9321, 0.9405, 0.9344, 0.9449, 0.9106, 0.8844, 
    0.8829, 0.8989, 0.798, 0.7464, 0.8225, 0.877, 0.8521, 0.9127, 
    0.9317, 0.9245, 0.9595, 0.9628, 0.9573, 0.9423, 0.9428, 0.5802, 
    0.6414, 0.5123, 0.57, 0.587, 0.5655, 0.5231, 0.517, 0.4694, 
    0.5459, 0.3745, 0.3274, 0.7936, 0.7821, 0.7297, 0.7227, 0.6814, 
    0.6608, 0.6721, 0.6202, 0.5924, 0.5659, 0.5448, 0.6138), 
    metric = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("APD", "ED"
    ), class = "factor")), .Names = c("K", "q", "rarity", "metric"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -48L))

library(ggplot2) 
ggplot(data=data, aes(x=q, y=rarity, colour=metric, shape=K))+ 
  ggtitle("Relationship")+
  xlab("rate of character change")+
  ylab("Correlation coefficient to average rarity")+
  geom_point()+
  geom_smooth(method=lm,se=FALSE)
```

Any advice on that?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You're getting two lines for each group becase it's being split by both `metric` and `K`. You really want the `shape` aesthetic to only apply to the point layer, not the smooth later. It's better just to move the `aes()` for that property there.

```
ggplot(data=data, aes(x=q, y=rarity, colour=metric))+ 
  ggtitle("Relationship")+
  xlab("rate of character change")+
  ylab("Correlation coefficient to average rarity")+
  geom_point(aes(shape=K))+
  geom_smooth(method=lm,se=FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: Key insight: specify the colors/shapes you don't want smooth to see in `geom_points(aes())` rather than in `ggplot(aes())`

Thanks MrFlick, vahab!

Comment: It is also always possible to re-specify any aesthetics as NULL in a geom you want to ignore that aesthetic. E.g. `geom_smooth(aes(shape = NULL))`.